# Does the unbalance of the pos and neg samples lead to the low variance of the neural network's outputs?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

I train a neural network and the batch size is 1000. I check the outputs from my model every time it fed with 1000 sample, and I find that the outputs, which shall be the predictions for the binary classification task. What confused me is that the the outputs in every batch has very low variance, the max prediction score is 0.25 and the min is above 0.1.  There are 25% positive samples in my dataset whose labels are 1.
So I want to know why the variance is so low. It seems that the model has no ability in the classification task, after several epochs training.

Comment: What's your architecture, loss function, activation functions, etc? How many samples do you have?

Comment: There are 500 millions samples and the loss function is log_loss in tensorflow.   There are two layers of MLP.

Comment: So you have two outputs using softmax activation as final layer before the loss function? I don't use tensorflow, but I believe `sigmoid_cross_entropy` with a single output is the conventional choice for binary classification (though equivalent to 2-output softmax+logloss).

Comment: I just use one output as logit and it will be functioned by the sigmoid. The output from sigmoid which ranges from 0 to 1 acts as the final prediction (probability).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could answer this question experimentally: artificially rebalance your classes and check if the outputs are likewise low-variance.

Moreover, examining the raw scores is not a great way to assess how well the model is doing. The real question is whether the scores do a "good job" of matching the true labels. There are a number of ways to measure this:

- cross entropy is lower when the predictions are closer to the true labels. Is the cross-entropy of your model lower than it would be by chance? Random scores have the value $\log(k)$ in expectation, for $k$ the number of classes.
- ROC AUC, a.k.a. the $c$-statistic, measures how well the model predictions separate the two classes. A value greater than 0.5 indicates that your model is better than chance.